# Can one use template specialization on a templated typedef?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, using, template-specialization

I would like to do something like the following (in c++11, c++14; not c++17):

```
template <class T>
using partner = void;

template<>
using partner<A> = X;

template<>
using partner<B> = Y;

template<>
using partner<C> = Z;
```

But I get a compilation error---

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’

---on the first template specialization.

Is such a thing possible? (I already know I can use a templated class with a `using` statement inside it. I'm hoping directly use the `using` statement without the class wrapper, since it's simpler and more elegant. If there's another simple, elegant solution, please share!)

Comment: `std::conditional_t` (with `std::is_same`) is an alternative, but I won't say it is more elegant.

Comment: one reason you can't do such a thing is that alias template is deduced context e.g. in case of being used in another template parameter

Answer (score 10):

You can't specialize alias templates.

You'll have to resort to normal, boring class template specialization:

```
template <class T> struct partner_t { using type = void; };
template <> struct partner_t<A> { using type = X; };
template <> struct partner_t<B> { using type = Y; };
template <> struct partner_t<C> { using type = Z; };

template <class T>
using partner = typename partner_t<T>::type;
```

---

Or we could get fancier

```
template <class T> struct tag { using type = T; };

template <class T> auto partner_impl(tag<T> ) -> tag<void>;
auto partner_impl(tag<A> ) -> tag<X>;
auto partner_impl(tag<B> ) -> tag<Y>;
auto partner_impl(tag<C> ) -> tag<Z>;

template <class T>
using partner = typename decltype(partner_impl(tag<T>{}))::type;
```